# How to replace \" with " in C#

Tags: c#

I am reading a text file containing some HTML text with escape chars, how to remove yellow highlighted characters and make it clean (I do not want to remove /* highlighted in orange)?

[image]

Comment: You don't. This is an artifact of how you are viewing the HTML (probably in a debugger)

Comment: The backslashes are not really there.  The viewer is adding them for display purposes only.

Comment: Can you verify with a text editor that the content is stored like that in the text file? How is the text file being generated?

Comment: the above screenshot is from the Notepad++, I opened a text file to show what is actually in the file.

Comment: Then it is an artifact of the code that writes it to the file! Please show code.

Comment: @ritu_o0o And you probably copied the value from the debugger, which injects the escape characters so you can distinguish between the end of the string and an actual quote character.

Comment: @ritu_o0o If you are _not_ viewing the code in the debugger, then share how you are viewing/writing the string

Comment: @DStanley you are right, I have copied the text from debugger into the notepad ++ and took a screenshot.

Comment: @ritu_o0o Then you have no escape characters to clean up - if you wrote the string to a file you'd see that there are no slashes before the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all occurrences of `\"`:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\\"", "");
```

To replace all occurences of `\"` with `"`:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

The first backslash is to escape the next character. So `\\\"` translates to `\"`.

Comment: @GregalMohorko I have tried this before posting my question but it does not work, maybe because the actual text which is shown in the screenshot was taken from the debugger